# Values not getting deleted in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am learning how to make a todo app using localStorage. I am making this app using Blackberry 10 Jquery theme. The problem is that sometimes the removeItem function on localStorage does not work.

See the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RGx84/)

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Insert items into the list.
2. Delete multiple items quickly by swiping.
3. Reload the page and see that 2-3 items still show up on screen and do not get deleted.

Please repeat this sometimes till the problem shows up.
What is the cause of this problem?

**Code:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="tasks-form">
            <input type="text" name="text-input" id="task" autofocus placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
        </form>
        <div id="tasks"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascipt**

```
        var i = 0;
       // Initial loading of tasks
       for( i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
         $("#tasks").prepend("<li id='task-"+ i +"'>" + localStorage.getItem('task-'+i) +"</li>");

       // Add a task
       $("#tasks-form").submit(function() {
         if (  $("#task").val() !== "" ) {
           localStorage.setItem( "task-"+i, $("#task").val() );
           $("#tasks").prepend("<li id='task-"+i+"'>"+localStorage.getItem("task-"+i)+"</li>");
           $("#task-" + i).css('display', 'none');
           $("#task-" + i).slideDown();
           $("#task").val("");
           i++;
         }
         return false;
       });


       $(document.body).on("swiperight","li",function() {
         localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr("id"));

     $(this).animate(
                    {
                        'margin-left':'600px','opacity':'0'
                    },'swing',
                    function(){

                        $(this).slideUp('fast',function(){$(this).remove();});
                }
                    );

         for(i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
           if( !localStorage.getItem("task-"+i)) {
             localStorage.setItem("task-"+i, localStorage.getItem('task-' + (i+1) ) );
             localStorage.removeItem('task-'+ (i+1) );
           }
         }
       });
```

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Comment: What if you call localStorage.clear(), still then it shows the list ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, I am using Chrome.

Comment: @UmairSaleem calling localStorage.clear() deletes all the entries and no item shows up after a refresh

Comment: @UmairSaleem I am using FIrefox and Chrome. The entries may or may not reappear. As I said earlier, this happens sometimes. Could you please try doing that again?